# how to run python script from html webpage with button click

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, cgi

I have written the below html code:

```
<script>
    function goPython(){
        $.ajax({
          url: "MYSCRIPT.py",
         context: document.body
        }).done(function() {
         alert('finished python script');;
        });
    }
</script>
```

and in myscript.py, i have included the following code, i am trying to run this myscript python script from html in godaddy cpanel, i have provided handler and cgi script in .htaccess

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

# enable debugging

import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
print 'Content-Type: text/plain'
print ''
print 'Hello World!'
```

I am expecting hello world print in the document.body on the current webpage, but it only saysfinished python script, and nothing else it shows on the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax call never actually uses the response from the python script. Adding the `data` parameter to the `.done()` function should get python's response.

```
<script>
function goPython(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "MYSCRIPT.py",
        context: document.body
    }).done(function(data) {
        alert('finished python script');
        alert(data)
    });
}
</script>
```